# execve fails with wrong arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec

I want to replace my program with an interactive Bash shell. Launching works in Golang (with `os/exec.Command`) and Python (`os.system`) but not when I want to replace the process using `syscall.Exec()` or `os.execve()`.

Demo Python code:

```
import os

# first try with fork: OK
os.system("/bin/bash --rcfile env.sh -i")

# second try with execve: FAIL (exit after reading env.sh)
os.execve("/bin/bash", ["--rcfile", "env.sh", "-i"], os.environ)
```

Contents of env.sh:

```
export PS1='interactive shell $ '
echo inside env.sh
ls -la /proc/self/fd
```

Python output:

```
$ echo "Start: $$"; python test.py; echo "End: $$";
Start: 684875
inside env.sh
total 0
lrwx------ 1 willem willem 64 mrt 31 14:03 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 willem willem 64 mrt 31 14:03 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 willem willem 64 mrt 31 14:03 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 willem willem 64 mrt 31 14:03 3 -> /proc/737221/fd
interactive shell $ exit <--- Control-D from me
inside env.sh
total 0
lrwx------ 1 willem willem 64 mrt 31 14:03 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 willem willem 64 mrt 31 14:03 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 willem willem 64 mrt 31 14:03 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 willem willem 64 mrt 31 14:03 3 -> /proc/737223/fd
End: 684875
```

Any ideas how to debug why Bash would exit at the second run?

Answer (score 2):

It's `execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "--rcfile", ...])`.

You are running `bash env.sh -i` - executing script `env.sh` with one argument `-i`, and process name set to `--rcfile`.

Comment: Thanks! I am blushing, this took me like 4 hours of debugging :D